# .NET deserialization - multiple types are returned

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, serialization

We have a framework built up whose API is this:

```
T Deserialize<T>(string to deserialize)
{
    //  XmlSerializer(typeof(T))
    //  deserialize and return
}
```

We've been passing it things like:

```
[XmlRoot("apple")]
public class Apple
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int AppleId { get; set; }
}
```

this works great when we are returned an apple, however, sometimes we are getting "notAnApple".  So I will either get "apple" or "notAnApple".  When I get "notAnApple", I get an exception.

As we have a lot of code built around this method, I would prefer not to go around changing things like the method signature.  I do, however, have full flexibility into passing whatever class I like into this deserialization method.

Comment: What are you trying to fix?  You want to reject instances of `notAnApple`?  You want to catch the exception?  You want to find a way to properly deserialize `notAnApple`?

Comment: If the type is Fruit you should be able to process both Apples and Oranges

Comment: If you're passing in data that will be deserialized as "notAnApple" where you want "Apple", the only way to fix that is not to pass in data that will deserialize as "notAnApple".

Comment: @PeterRitchie is there some magic trick where I could pass Container, which has an Apple and a NotAnApple field, and the xml is magically deserialized to the right place?

Comment: Yes folks I know I am asking for something crazy

Comment: @mellamokb optimally I would like to be able to deserialize both.  For now, I would also accept - does not throw an exception when "notAnApple" is passed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you "know" exactly what you're serializing and deserializing.  e.g. you may serialize like this:

```
serializer.Serialize(stream, new Apple());
serializer.Serialize(stream, new notAnApple());
```

Then you'd serialize like:

```
Apple apple = (Apple)deserialzer.Deserialize(stream);
notAnApple peach = (notAnApple)desserializer.Deserialize(stream);
```

You don't normally randomly try to deserialize data to figure out what it is that you're deserializing.  Technically you already know because you have a specific file format or a specific stream format.

Comment: So, clearly I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Why would you serialize notAnApple if it's an error to deserialize it?

Comment: because notAnApple is an error object that tells us what went wrong.  It would be great if we could deserialize the error object that came across the wire or the apple, if that came across the wire.

Comment: You need to know the error object is there *before* you deserialize it.  It's it stick in there at random places, you'll have to intercept the exception and deal with the notAnApple object (or whatever was deserialized).  FWIW, I don't recommend randomly changing the format of the data you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: Alternatively, you could add a flag in the stream to tell you whether the next object is an error or not; but, that seems to be waste--I would put error objects at specific, expected, points in the stream.

Comment: In this case, and in life. :)  if you can't be sure what you're deserializing, you have to deal with it by way of exceptions...